Is there a way to create an empty instance that implements the IOrderedEnumerable?
The GetOrderedEnum function returns an enumeration ordered by fields from the names array. Everything is working, but I am worried about one question.
class Program {

    class SomeData(int A, int B, int C) {

        public int A = A, B = B, C = C;
        public override string ToString() => $"({A}, {B}, {C})";
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> GetOrderedEnum<T>(
        IEnumerable<T> src, params string[] names) where T : class {

        var t = src.GetType().GetElementType();
        var orderedEnum = src.OrderBy(p => 1);  // <- this
        foreach (var f in names)
            orderedEnum = orderedEnum.ThenBy(t!.GetField(f)!.GetValue);
        return orderedEnum;
    }

    static void Main() {

        SomeData[] src = [
            new(3, 3, 1),
            new(3, 2, 2),
            new(3, 1, 3),
            new(2, 3, 1),
            new(2, 2, 2),
            new(2, 1, 3),
            new(1, 3, 1),
            new(1, 2, 2),
            new(1, 1, 3),
        ];

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine, GetOrderedEnum(src, "A", "B", "C")));
    }
}

Can I replace OrderBy(p => 1) with something? Firstly, to remove unnecessary comparisons, and secondly, to emphasize that the order is completely determined by the parameter.

No, you can't create an empty instance to call .ThenBy without calling .OrderBy first, best you can do is add a comment, or move the orderby which creates your initial instance to a helper method called 'CreateEmptyOrderedEnumerable' or the like

Edit: apologies, I realize that I answered how I would think of implementing rather than directly what you asked (and for which I'd have to agree with @sam-fessler the answer is "no").

Try
  static IEnumerable<T> GetOrderedEnum2<T>(IEnumerable<T> src, params string[] names) where T : class
  {
    if (names.Length < 1) return src;
    var t = src.GetType().GetElementType();
    if (t == null) throw new ApplicationException();
    var fields = names.Select(t.GetField).Where(f => f != null).ToArray();
    if (fields.Length != names.Length) throw new ApplicationException();
    var orderedEnum = src.OrderBy(x => fields[0]!.GetValue(x));
    IOrderedEnumerable<T> result = orderedEnum;
    foreach (var info in fields.Skip(1)) result = result.ThenBy(info!.GetValue);
    return result;
  }

or a bit more terse (I find more difficult to read), replacing the last 3 lines with
return fields.Skip(1).Aggregate(orderedEnum, (current, info) => current.ThenBy(info!.GetValue));


I liked your implementation more than mine. Thank you.
